# Angular/JS Validation not clearing/revalidating on arrow down

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation

I have a form that checks to see if a credit card expiration date is before or after the current date.  For the most part, it works.  However, if you navigate the form a specific way, the validation doesn't work quite right.

Basically, if you use the mouse to click on fields everything works as it should. If you use the arrow keys to switch the values, it doesn't.

This can be seen in the code below and at the codepen I did [here](http://codepen.io/raedwa01/pen/gaWGWq/).

If you start with focus on the Text box, tab to Exp Month and arrow down to 1 or 2 then tab over to Exp Year.  Here, arrow down to 2015 and you will see text saying the date has to be after today.  (This is written in October 2015, so the test will change depending on when you look at this post).  The text here is expected.  What's not expected is if you arrow down to 2016 in the same box, the text does not clear.  Essentially, ng-show is not retesting the code even though something changed in the model.  If you arrow down to 2017, the text hides and all is ok.  Even stranger is that you can now arrow up and down all you want and evaluation works as expected.

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('ccDate', function($scope) {
  $scope.ccExpireMonths = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "1"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "2"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "3"
  }, {
    id: 4,
    name: "4"
  }, {
    id: 5,
    name: "5"
  }, {
    id: 6,
    name: "6"
  }, {
    id: 7,
    name: "7"
  }, {
    id: 8,
    name: "8"
  }, {
    id: 9,
    name: "9"
  }, {
    id: 10,
    name: "10"
  }, {
    id: 11,
    name: "11"
  }, {
    id: 12,
    name: "12"
  }]
  $scope.expireMonth = "";
  var currentDate = new Date();
  $scope.currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();

  function getCreditCardExpireYears() {
    var expireYears = new Array();
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      expireYears[i] = $scope.currentYear + i;
    };
    return expireYears;
  }
  $scope.ccExpireYears = getCreditCardExpireYears();
  $scope.validateCCExpireDate = function() {
    var today = new Date();
    var minDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth());
    var ccExpireDate = new Date($scope.expireYear, $scope.expireMonth - 1);
    return ccExpireDate < minDate;
  };
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="App">
  <div ng-controller="ccDate">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <label for="some=text">Some Text</label>
        <input type="text" id="some-text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="expire-month" required="">Exp. Month</label>
        <select id="expire-month" class="form-control ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" title="Select the card expiration month" ng-model="expireMonth" ng-options="month.id as month.name for month in ccExpireMonths" ng-required="expireMonth"
        required="required">
        </select>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="expire-year" required="">Exp. Year</label>
        <select id="expire-year" class="form-control ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" title="Select the card expiration year" ng-model="expireYear" ng-options="year for year in ccExpireYears" ng-required="expireYear" required="required">

        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="expire-month-value" ng-show="validateCCExpireDate() && expireMonth && expireYear" class="error-text form-group col-md-3 ng-hide">Month/Year combination must not be in the past.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's a known issue in Chrome (and probably Firefox): 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4216

> gkalpak commented on Jun 17
>
> @iiminov, as already mentioned, this is a known issue and is due to a bug in Chrome.
>   Until the bug is resolved, the solution/workaround is to use an explicit empty option.
>
> (It is not clear what you are trying to demonstrate (and how it is different from the demos already discussed).)

More details and a workaround here:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9134

> Narretz commented on Aug 13
>
> I just closed some duplicates of this issue, so here's a quick recap:
>
> Chrome (Blink) / Safari (webkit) has a bug not firing change when an option is removed. Bug filed as https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=415505
>
> Firefox basically follows the "spirit of the spec" by not firing change when the select value is changed via keyboard, but Chrome and IE do it, so it coud be considered a bug. Tracked as https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=126379.
>
> As a workaround, you can add a directive that fires the change event on keyup (thanks to @gkalpak for this):
>
> ```
> directive('changeOnKeyup', function changeOnKeyupDirective() {
>     return function changeOnKeyupPostLink(scope, elem) {
>         elem.on('keyup', elem.triggerHandler.bind(elem, 'change'));
>     };
> });
> ```